# Can we create two modules? not a liabrary module

Tags: android, android-studio, module

Am new to android studio. In my application i need to add a module **TestModule** which will do some exam test related functionality. This module need to use some database classes which are there in Main module. If i created **TestModule** as library module it wont allow me to access classes from Main Module. I need to use this **TestModule** in another Applications also. So what will be the good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create whatever Android App and/or Android Library modules you like and make any one depend on another.

Open the Project Structure dialog view File > Project Structure (or command-; on mac). Use the small plus symbol near the top left to add a new module. The New Module wizard will let you choose what kind of module to make.

After you've created your modules, highlight any one on the left pane and click the "Dependencies" tab on the right pane. Near the bottom is a plus symbol to add a dependency. Choose "Module dependency" and select another module(s).

Comment: As far as I know, any module can depend on any other module. Typically an "app" module (or multiple app modules) depends on a "library" module (or multiple library modules), because generally libraries encapsulate some specific functionality that you want to share. So you might consider making a library module with your common logic, and then two app modules that each depend on the library module.

Comment: What I described will not be a circular dependency. What I described was two app modules (A1 and A2) that both depend on a third module that is a Library module (L). L has no dependencies. A1 depends on L. A2 depends on L. No circularity at all.

Comment: yeah, there will not be any circularity in this case .But the question still remains. How can i access class of App module to Library module?